# How do you prove that $\lim f(x) = 0$, when $f$ is rapidly decreasing?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, fourier-analysis

Let $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be rapidly decreasing in the sense than $\sup_{x \in \Bbb{R}} |x|^k |f^{(\ell)}(x)| \lt \infty$ for all $k, \ell \geq 0$, where $f^{(\ell)}$ is the $\ell$th derivative.  It seems like $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$, but how do I prove it?

What's important is that $f$ is rapidly decreasing, not necessarily that its derivatives are too.  But the Schwartz space just happens to be what I'm working with and it's closed under indefinite derivative taking.

Comment: Here's a hint: if $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |x|^k|f^{(l)}(x)| \le M(l,k) < \infty$ ($M$ is a function of $l$ and $k$ but we know it is always finite), then you know that $|f^{(l)}(x)|\le\frac{M(l,k)}{|x|^k}$. Particularly, this has to hold for $l = 0$. You have to be a little careful with what happens at the origin, but it's not hard to piece together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$f(x)=\frac1x\cdot x\,f(x)\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\ldots$$

and remember:

$$g(x)\;\text{bounded in some neighborhood of $\,x_0\,$ and}\;\lim_{x\to x_0}h(x)=0\implies \lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)h(x)=0$$

and the above is easily generalized when $\;x_0=\infty\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

We have that $\sup |x|^k |f(x)| \lt \infty$, say it equals $M$.  Then for all $x, \ |x|^k |f(x)| \leq M \implies |f(x)| \leq \frac{M}{|x|^k} \implies \forall \epsilon \gt 0, \ \exists x_0 \ s.t. \ x \geq x_0 \implies |f(x) - 0 | \lt \epsilon$.  Proof:
$$
\frac{M}{|x|^k} \lt \epsilon \\
\iff \\\
\sqrt[k]{\frac{M}{\epsilon}} \lt |x|
$$

So choose any $x_0 \gt 0$ satisfying the above.